# Play store app up-gradation issues

Tags: android, google-play, keystore

I have gone through several threads regarding this, I have multiple scenarios associated with this question, so I asked new question.

I have following scenarios;

- My app is live on play store and lost the `Keystore`

  1. As far as I searched on google SO, I cannot update without `keystore`. So, Can I remove the production release apk from play store and then upload new apk with new keystore with same `bundle id`?
  2. Or any solution to use same bundle id for new app?
- Can I upload beta for that app with new keystore

  1. As I have already release build available on play store, so is it possible to upload updated apk in `beta release` (in general)
  2. is that possible in my scenario?

> What are suggestion in case I cannot solve my issue with above
>   situation?

Comment: User will not be able to update your application without uninstalling the previous one, since the signature does not match your previous one. In your case I would create a new application with a new package name.

Comment: Does matter to user, because app is recently uploaded and just downloaded by few people @GiovanniTerlingen

Comment: Then I would just publish the app under a different package name.

Comment: can I do as my requirement. i.e; delete that release and upload new with all together new keystore @GiovanniTerlingen